# how can I add symbol in asp.net texbox

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add symbol to readonly textbox.

I have tried like below.

aspx file:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="XcoordTextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

aspx.cs file:

```
XcoordTextbox.Text= "&#9986;";
```

But the output `&#9986;` text in the box. But I need symbol only in a button or textbox.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the code to the actual symbol:

```
XcoordTextbox.Text = HttpUtility.UrlDecode("&#9986");
```

I guess you could also try with the HtmlDecode method.

There are other overloads where you can also specify the encoding.